# db.create_all() doesn't throw any errors and doesn't create the tables

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's my file structure:

```
/
/apitestproject
    /models
        __init__.py
        users.py
        items.py
    /resources
        __init__.py
        users.py
        items.py
    __init__.py
    index.py
.deployment
deploy.cmd
requirements.txt
run_waitress_server.py
runserver.py
web.config
```

Inside my main `__init__.py` file I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'admin_user@pracap',
    'pw': 'the_password',
    'db': 'apitest',
    'host': 'pracap.postgres.database.azure.com',
    'port': '5432',
}
URL = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(POSTGRES['user'], POSTGRES['pw'], POSTGRES['host'], POSTGRES['port'], POSTGRES['db'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = URL
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import apitestproject.index
```

In my `index.py` file I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from apitestproject import app, db


@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "I'm the default route"
```

And in my `/models/users.py` file i have:

```
from apitestproject import db

class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.column(db.string, primary_key=True)
    name = db.column(db.string(50))
    address = db.column(db.string(144))
    salary = db.column(db.numeric(12, 2))
    position = db.column(db.string(50))
    password = db.column(db.string(50))
```

The console is not throwing any errors and I can run everything right without even a single hint of an error. But the tables are not created. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I've been working with flask/sqlalchemy for just over a month now and I'm starting to work with DB's.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is runserver.py yor running script??? if yes please add this code

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to work with flask-migrate as a good alternative :
just find [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one#toc-migration) tutorial about it :

a short descrition about it is here :

> Migrations allow us to manage changes we make to the models, and
>   propagate these changes in the database. For example, if later on we
>   make a change to a field in one of the models, all we will need to do
>   is create and apply a migration, and the database will reflect the
>   change.

after installing it via

```
pip install flask-migrate
```

edit your **init**.py like this :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'admin_user@pracap',
    'pw': 'the_password',
    'db': 'apitest',
    'host': 'pracap.postgres.database.azure.com',
    'port': '5432',
}
URL = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(POSTGRES['user'], POSTGRES['pw'], POSTGRES['host'], POSTGRES['port'], POSTGRES['db'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = URL
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

import apitestproject.index
```

and then edit your index.py by removing the db creatation you will do it via command line .

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from apitestproject import app, db

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "I'm the default route"
```

after that go to your application directory and export the flask app and what are the run script of your app?? :

in cmd do this :

```
export FLASK_APP=your_runScript.py
```

and then the 2 following commands to migrate the db :

```
flask db init
```

to create the migration folder

and :

flask db migrate 
to  create the first migration 
and :

```
flask db upgrade
```

to upgrade changes to the db

find more [here](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) about the flask-migrate package